# How can i make wcf 3.5 Rest Service which returns a dataset in Json and xml format?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a wcf 3.5 rest service which gets a dataset from database, i want to sent this data as xml or json according to the mime type defined in client script.

Comment: you need to create two endpoints in your config file one to expose the service as xml and other as json

Comment: try this : http://benjii.me/2010/05/how-to-return-multiple-formats-with-wcf-including-xml-json-and-atom/

Comment: In the header you have Content-Type that determines if the client accepts xml or json. Hence you can find that in your service method and accordingly send it back. By default if you dont specify any response format on your service method, the framework looks at the content-type set and automatically sends the response in the one that the client understands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build your operation url(either xml or Json) to http request.
for e.g

```
makeCall(doXML)
makeCall(doJson)
```

and use Post method to **service.svc/operation**

on your service contracts build 2 different method with WebInvoke attribute to response with appropriate format.

```
[WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)
        DataContractResult doXML(object parameters);

[WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
        DataContractResult doJson(object parameters);
```

for .NET 3.5 and enable use of non-ASP.NET client, you need to configure the address endpoint.

for detail, you could refer [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb472488%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).